# Actualizar variable de cantidad de divs con length

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando un script que cuenta la cantidad de `div` con una clase específica. El script funciona, pero no se actualiza el resultado cuando los `div` se ocultan o se muestran.

Código:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.comodiF').on("change",function() { 
  $('.'+$(this).attr('data-name')).toggle(this.checked);
  }).change();
});
$(function () {
  var counta =  $("#sub3 .rowSub").length;
  document.getElementById("numSals5").innerHTML = counta
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filter-options2" aria-labelledby="menu1">
  <div>
    <div id="filterControls2">
      <li>
        <input class="comodiF" data-name="category-semicama" type="checkbox" checked name="category-semicama" id="category-semicama" value="category-semicama">
        <label for="category-semicama">Semi-Cama</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input class="comodiF" data-name="category-cama" type="checkbox" checked id="category-cama" name="category-cama" value="category-cama">
        <label for="category-cama">Salón-Cama</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input  class="comodiF" data-name="category-salon-cama-vip" type="checkbox" checked id="category-salon-cama-vip" name="category-salon-cama-vip" value="category-salon-cama-vip">
        <label for="category-salon-cama-vip">Salón-Cama-VIP</label>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
<div id="sub3">
  <div class="rowSub category-semicama">
    <span class="fL">Semi-Cama:</span>
    <span class="fR">$18000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="rowSub category-salon-cama-vip">
    <span class="fL">Semi-Cama:</span>
    <span class="fR">$18000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="rowSub category-cama">
    <span class="fL">Semi-Cama:</span>
    <span class="fR">$18000</span>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<span id="numSals5"></span> servicios disponibles
```

¿Cómo se hace esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Necesitas contar los divs que son visibles con el selector `:visible`.  Algo asi:

```js
$(function () {
    var counta =  $("#sub3 .rowSub").length;
    document.getElementById("numSals5").innerHTML = counta
});

$("#boton").click(function(){
  $("#asd").toggle();
  var counta =  $("#sub3 .rowSub:visible").length;
  document.getElementById("numSals5").innerHTML = counta
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sub3">
  <div id="asd" class="rowSub">
    div1
  </div>
  
  <div class="rowSub">
    div2
  </div>
  
  <div class="rowSub">
    div3
  </div>
  
</div>

<br>
Cantidad de divs con clase rowSub: <span id="numSals5"></span>

<br><br>
<button id="boton">TOGGLE DIV1</button>
```

Comment: Bien! Funcionó. Y si tengo lo mismo pero con un checkbox? Tampoco se me actualiza
https://codepen.io/alejandrov90/pen/PVyZQV

Comment: Seria el mismo codigo.

Comment: No me lo agarra, podrías verlo? Me esta volviendo loco, porfa!
Actualicé el codepen

Comment: Solo agrega las dos lineas de mi respuesta despues del toggle.